# reverse function and append function to custom list standard ml

Tags: function, append, reverse, sml, ml

I want to make a function that reverse a mylist value. I wrote code but it isnt working, and I'd appreciate any tips or help.

the datatype code:

```
datatype 'element mylist = 
  NIL
| CONS 'element * 'element mylist;
```

and the functions I wrote are:

```
fun reverse NIL = NIL
  | reverse (CONS(x, xs)) = CONS((reverse xs), x);
```

I also want to write a function that appends 2 mylist values, I have some cases but it didnt work, i though of the following:

```
fun append NIL = fn NIL => NIL
  | append NIL = fn (CONS(x, xs)) => CONS(x, xs)
  | append (CONS(x, xs)) = fn NIL => CONS(x, xs)
  | append (CONS(x, xs)) = fn (CONS(y, ys)) => append xs (CONS(y, ys));
```

but it is not working, giving me error, what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `append` function, you made two mistakes:

- Duplicated pattern matching cases of `append NIL` and `append (CONS(x, xs))`.
- Non-exhaustive pattern matching in lambda of `fn NIL => ...` and the like.

Logic of `append` is also incorrect. It should be something like:

```
fun append NIL ys = ys
  | append (CONS(x, xs)) ys = CONS(x, append xs ys)
```

The function `reverse` has a type mismatch error. Since `reverse xs` is a list, `CONS(reverse xs, x)` doesn't type check. A quick fix is to use `append` for implementing `reverse`:

```
fun reverse NIL = NIL
  | reverse (CONS(x, xs)) = append (reverse xs) (CONS(x, NIL))
```

Comment: I didnt quite understand the duplicated pattern matching cases u mentioned, each case has a different fn inside it, why is it still considered duplicated?

Comment: Because the left hand-side parts before `=` are the same, the compiler cannot differentiate between them.

Comment: I see, so if I want to make something similar to the 4 cases i have before, so in the fn statement, if I used an if for the second parameter will it be the same as what I want in the 4 cases?
Its irrelevant just what to know for future referece

Comment: Yes or better if you use explicit arguments like `append NIL NIL = ...` to have 4 clearly different cases.

Answer (score 3):

A classic way to reverse a list, is to use a tail recursive helper function, like so:

```
fun helper accumulator NIL = accumulator
  | helper accumulator CONS(x, xs) = helper CONS(x, accumulator) xs
```

Now reverse is simply:

```
val reverse = helper NIL
```